# android.process.acore has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I try to run the android emulator it gives me following error:

> android.process.acore has stopped
>   unexpectedly force close

I cannot run any application.  Can any one guide me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I had the sampe problem, this is the solution : 
The solution:
Settings –> Applications –> Manage Applications –> All (button on the top that lets you see all applications) –> scroll down to “Contacts Storage” –> Click on “Clear Data”.

IT WORKED EVEN IN THE EMULATOR, you should do this to every emulator type you want to use, 
this is where I found the solutions : 
http://www.shaneycrawford.com/2011/12/how-to-fix-the-android-process-acore-problem-on-an-android-device/

Comment: @Bhimbim you should answer with this so I can vote it up. In my case the accepted answer is not correct, I get this on all AVDs no matter what, this solved my issue.

Comment: same here, i created a very basic android app with only a button and a text box, the emulator doesnt run for me no matter how i set the virtual device

Answer (score 11, accepted):

actually what happened due to abnomal restart of my machine AVD got corrupted and when i created new one every application is working fine..

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not the proper way to create new emulator for every new application. Maybe your API version problem is the first checkout there.

Comment: The OP's answer was that he created a single new emulator, and that single new emulator worked for all applications.