# Android process acore error in SDK emulator Eclipse

Tags: android, process, android-emulator

When ever I run and test android application on android SDK emulator, it shows this error at first and display it after 1 minute automatically.
I don't know how to overcome it.
Please, sort it out.
 You can see error in screen shot mentioned below:
 [image]

Comment: post your logcat trace

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of known fixes that have managed to sort this similar problem out.

1. The AVD does not have enough RAM. Try increasing the RAM of the AVD by editing it from the AVD Manager. *Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9384040/450534*
2. The AVD you are using may have been corrupted. The solution is to delete the current AVD and create new one with the same settings (if that is important to your apps functioning). *Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2199621/450534*